# How to send html content in c# for send grid email

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am try to send email via send grid using c# library.below is my code

```
var apiKey ="xxxxxxxxx";//dumy
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var from = new EmailAddress("asdasd@gmail.com", "Example User");
var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
var to = new EmailAddress("asdasd2@gmail.com", "Example User");
var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
var ww = "www.google.com";
var email = "asdasd2@gmail.com"

var htmlContent = string.Format(@"<strong>Hi{0}</strong>
<p>You are invited to  signup in  portal.You can signup using below signup button</p>
<p><a href={1}>Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p>",email,ww);
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);     
var response =  client.SendEmailAsync(msg).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

i converted the html content to string and execute the code .But no email is received .is there anything wrong with my code ?.Before i get email when  htmlContent is

> < strong>Hi</ strong>